# Alerting only 1st Product Code from table?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, I have a table emitting data from database table.

```
    //Display the simplex table
    echo "<div id='simptable'>";
    $sqlGet = "SELECT * FROM simplex_list";

    //Grab data from database
    $sqlSimplex = mysqli_query($connect , $sqlGet)or die("Error retrieving data!");

    //Loop to display all records on webpage in a table
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Product Code</th><th>Description</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlSimplex , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo "<input type='text' id='sim' value='".$row['s_code']."' readonly>";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['description'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' id='com' name='complexcode' value='$newProductID'>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<input type='text' size='7' id='userqty'>";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo "<input type='button'  onclick='addthis()' value='Add!'>";
        echo "</td></tr>";  
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";
```

And I try to alert the 'Product Code' here when the user clicks 'Add' button....

```
function addthis() {
      var scode = $('#sim').val();
            alert(scode);   
    }
```

The problem is it only alerts the first Product Code in the table. That from row 1.

Example:

Product code    Name   More 
123             Toy    'Add'
321             Food   'Add'
555             Pen    'Add'

So if I click on 'Add' for food or pen it will still alert 123..

Any ideas?

Comment: An ID needs to be unique...

Comment: @Naruto didn't work :/

Comment: You are looping over your result set, and assigning every input the same id (id='sim').  ID must be unique.  You should generate a unique ID in your loop, perhaps by incrementing a number and appending it to 'sim' so that every input has its own id.  Then target the element event with $('[id^=sim]')

Answer (score 0):

> ID must be unique.

You can do something like following. Add parameter in `onclick` function. Which will be `ID` of row.

```
echo "<input type='button'  onclick='addthis(".$row['s_code'].")' value='Add!'>";
                                                 ^^^
```

Parameter added in above code. Now javascript function can be:

```
function addthis(scope) {
  alert(scode);   
}
```

Comment: nothing happens after I don't this..not even an alert

Comment: Updated my php `echo` line try this. Do not forgot to check in console may be you are getting any error. and remove `ID` from `input`

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in comments, the ID of your input must be unique.  You're currently assigning 'sim' as the ID to every input in your loop over the data results.

One approach to fix this:

```
$i = 0;
echo "<input type='text' id='sim" .  $i ."' value='".$row['s_code']."' readonly>";
```

And then add a unqiue id to your button using the same incrementor:

```
echo "<input type='button'  id='btn" . $i . "' value='Add!'>";
$i++;  //then increment
```

Notice that the button and the input have the same number at the end of their id.  You can use this to parse the id of the button and use it to find the input.
Tie the click event with:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="btn"]', function() {
     var id = $(this).attr('id').split('btn')[1];
     var val = $('#sim' + id).val();
     console.log(val);
     //do other stuff
});
```

**UPDATE:**  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d97xzcmr/1/)

Comment: I corrected the placement of the quotes around the id, and the targetting of the input id (it was missing '#')

Comment: This won't work for me at all. I've made the changes you recommended but the alert won't even function now..

Comment: I didn't give complete code.  For example, you need to loop over whatever creates you input html in order for the incrementor to work.  I'll mock something up in JSFiddle to demo.

Comment: I've updated by answer with a fiddle link at the bottom.

Comment: thank you I'll let you know how it goes! Much appreciated!